# Script working in Windows 7 but not working in windows 8?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, autoit

This script is working in windows 7 but in windows 8 it is failing..

```
#include <FF.au3>
#include <_FF_AutoLogin.au3>
#include <_FFEx.au3>
$url ="file:///D:/1.html"
$formID = ""
$formUID = "usernameInput"
$uName = "Sandya_N"
$formPID = "passwordInput"
$pwd = "Password@123"
$formSubmit = "ID_LOGON"
Run(@ProgramFilesDir & "\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe " & $url, "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
If _FFConnect () Then
_FFSetValueById($formUID,$uName)
_FFSetValueById($formPID,$pwd)
EndIf
_FFClick($formSubmit,"id")
```

actually I have form without form tag that is why i am not preferring `_FF_AutoLogin($uName,$pwd,$url)`

In Windows 7 output is:

```
FFSend: try{window.content.top.document.getElementById('usernameInput').value='Sandya_N'}catch(e){'_FFCmd_Err';};
__FFRecv: Sandya_N
__FFSend: try{window.content.top.document.getElementById('passwordInput').value='Password@123'}catch(e){'_FFCmd_Err';};
__FFRecv: Password@123
```

but in windows 8:

```
    FFSend: try{window.content.top.document.getElementById('usernameInput').value='Sandya_N'}catch(e){'_FFCmd_Err';};
        __FFRecv: _FFCmd_Err
        __FFSend: try{window.content.top.document.getElementById('passwordInput').value='Password@123'}catch(e){'_FFCmd_Err';};


 __FFRecv: _FFCmd_Err
```

that means it is not not taking id of html....What is wrong?

Comment: Do you use the exact same browser version?

Comment: No in windows 7 I am using IE9, but in windows 8 I am using IE10

Comment: But you use the Firefox UDFs?

Comment: yes sorry i got confused the same script i tried to implement in ie also.

Comment: And according to Firefox: Do you use the same versions? If not, did you try to use the version from your Windows 7 in your Windows 8 installation? Does this produce the same error?

Comment: it got resolved by replacing with same of firefox in windows 8 thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually it is not issue with script script is fine.might be the web page you are using is not a standard web page.i have tested the script it is working fine.

```
_FF_AutoLogin($uName,$pwd,$url)
```

(or)

```
_FFSetValue($uName,$formUID,"id")
  _FFSetValue($pwd,$formPID,"id")
```

(Or)
    _FFSetValueById($formUID,$uName)
    _FFSetValueById($formPID,$pwd)(
or)

```
$sObject &= ".document.getElementById('passwordInput')"
$sObject =".getElementById('" & $formUID & "')"
_FFCmd($sObject & ".value='" & $uName & "'")
$sObj =".getElementById('" & $formPID & "')"
_FFCmd($sObj & ".value='" & $pwd & "'")
```

Comment: all these are ways of filling forms in ff